# Laravel me guarda archivos temporales

Tags: laravel

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación donde mi backend es Laravel y mi frontend es Angular, es un formulario donde el usuario tiene la posibilidad de subir una imagen, la imagen la quiero guardar en el storage. El problema es que en vez de guardar la imagen me guarda una carpeta con el nombre que le asigno y dentro de esta carpeta hay un archivo temporal.

Puede ser un problema de headers en mi parte de Angular? o tengo algo mal en mi codigo de backend?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $values = $request->except('img');
        $data = $request->only('img[]');
        if($request->hasFile('img')){
            foreach($request->file("img") as $image)
            {
                $name = Str::random(10).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image->move("storage/img/".$name);
                $data[] = $name;
            }
        }
        $tramite = Tramite::create($values);
        $tramite->img = json_encode($data);
        $tramite->save();

        return response()->json($tramite, 201);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución! la comparto por si alguien tiene el mismo error

Modifique esta parte del codigo

```
$image->move("storage/img/". $name);
```

por esta:

```
$image->move("storage/img/", $name);
```